# Using outer join and group by to solve the query

Tags: sql, database, select, group-by, outer-join

```
EMPLOYEE (fmane, minit, lname, ssn, birthdate, address, sex, salary, superssn, dno)     KEY: ssn
DEPARTMENT (dname, dnumber, mgrssn, mgrstartdate)               KEY: dnumber.
PROJECT  (pname, pnumber, plocation, dnum)                          KEY: pnumber.
WORKS_ON (essn, pno, hours)                                         KEY: (essn, pno)
DEPENDENT  (essn, dependent-name, sex, bdate, relationship)             KEY: (essn, dependent-name
```

I want to use outer join and group by to find out the following info, is that possible?

Get the SS and last first name of employees who are either

1) work as a department manager

OR

2) work as a supervisor of any employees

What I have so far is:

```
Select e.ssn, e.lname, e.fname
From employee e, department d
where d.mgrssn = e.ssn

union(?)

select s.ssn, s.lname, s.fname
From employee e2, employee s 
where e.superssn = s.ssn;
```

1) I think my union is wrong, is there anyway I can change it, like using outer join and group by to get what I need.

2) Also since I use two empoyees, one tutor told me I can use employee1 and employee2 to differentiate them, is that right? Are there anyways not using two employees identification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.ssn, e.lname, e.fname
FROM employee e,
  (SELECT mgrssn AS mgrssn
    FROM department
  UNION
  SELECT superssn AS mgrssn
    FROM employee) m
  WHERE e.ssn = m.mgrssn;
```

should work.

I'm not sure how either an outer join or a GROUP BY would serve you here; one returns rows from one table which have *no* corresponding row in a second table, while the other is used for condensing multiple rows into one via aggregate functions.

I'm also not sure what

> 2) Also since I use two empoyees, one tutor told me I can use employee1 and employee2 to differentiate them, is that right? Are there anyways not using two employees identification?

means. You could use `employee1` and `employee2` as *aliases* for `employee`, which would allow you to make multiple independent references to the same table, but however many aliases you use, there's still only one `employee` table in the database.

Comment: so basically WHERE e.ssn = m.mgrssn is joint table? because there is employee and manager are not connected before and therefore cannot share information?

Comment: Right. That's the "other" syntax for an inner join.

Comment: Thanks! also what is the m before WHERE e.ssn = m.mgrssn; is that a typo?

Comment: That's the table alias for the subquery which allows you to reference it as a pseudotable in the WHERE clause. It might actually not be needed here, since `mgrssn` unambiguously comes from the subquery, but it's still a good idea and some DBMSs might complain about its absence.

Answer (score 0):

1). Your `UNION` is correct! But you miss:

```
From employee e2, employee s 
where e.superssn = s.ssn;
```

Change to:

```
From employee e, employee s   -- replace e2 to e
where e.superssn = s.ssn;
```

2). Yes, you can! For me, to differentiate 2 empls, you can use ssn, because it's unique!